# Upload an image to a folder and get its path name

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload, insert

I have a form with a file input field:

```
<tr align="left">
    <td>Image :</td>
    <td align="left">
        <input type="file" name="ImageFile" size="18">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I then do stuff with this image file on submit:

```
$image_tmpname = $_FILES['ImageFile']['name'];
$imgdir = "blogImages/";
$imgname = $imgdir.$image_tmpname;

$blogs = new Blogs();

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'], $imgname);
    $insert = $blogs->insertBlog($heading, $article, $date, $imgname);
```

The directory I want to save the images is called `blogImages` and is in the same directory as the above.

You may notice in the above I call on a function called `insertBlog` within the class `Blogs'. Insert blog takes all the info and inputs the data to a mysql table. The code for`insertBlog` is:

```
function insertBlog($heading, $article, $date, $imgname){
        $query = "INSERT INTO Blogs (BlogTitle, MainArticle, PostDate, Image) VALUES ('$heading', '$article', '$date', '$imgname')";        
        $oDatabase = new database;
        $connection = $oDatabase->Connect();
        if (!mysql_select_db($oDatabase->Name(), $connection))
            $oDatabase->ShowError("Blogs.insertBlog");

        if (!(@ mysql_query ($query, $connection)))
            $oDatabase->ShowError("Blogs.insertBlog");

        return (mysql_insert_id());
    }
```

When a user fills out a form, it stores all the other information correctly in the MySQL table apart from the image information. Also, it doesn't store the actual image in the `blogImages` folder. So how do I get this script to upload the image to the `blogImages` folder and store its path in the mysql table. At the moment it doesnt not store the image in the db and only put the value `blogImages/` in the image path field in my MySQL table.

Comment: Did you check if the upload actually succeeded? `if ($_FILES['ImageFile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { die("Upload failed"); }`.

Comment: it didnt upload because when I go to the `blogImages` folder nothings actually there

Comment: So either it didn't upload at all, or you've got a permissions/path problem. Your code assumes success everyhwere, which is a bad idea. Start putting in error checking.move_uploaded_file returns false if that fails. uploads have a non-zero error code if they failed, etc...

Comment: where in my code where would i put this? `if ($_FILES['ImageFile']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { die("Upload failed"); }`

Comment: somewhere BEFORE you start manipulating the upload.

Comment: Yer, it said upload failed, but didnt tell me why

Comment: Probably a permission problem. Verify the directory can be written to: `echo is_writable('blogImages') ? 'is writable' : 'not writable';`

Comment: echo out the error code, the values are defined here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transfer a file you must specify `multipart/form-data` `enctype` in HTML.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
```